# AWS event logs command

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, aws-api-gateway, nagios, nagiosxi

[image: AWS Event log]
I am trying to find a cli-command which will report the latest alerts reported by AWS such as operational issues, security notifications and so on. Is there a cli-command for this task (image)?

FYI: Goal is to get the latest alerts and publish in NAGIOS

Comment: [AWS CLI for Personal Health Dashboard](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/health/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks John. Found the command:

`aws health describe-events --filter regions=<region1, region2, region3>,eventStatusCodes=open| jq '.events |= unique_by(.eventTypeCode)''`